# How to secure Buy Now Paypal button?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-buttons

I want to create a "Pay what you want" paypal button with minimum amount set.
I am adding the following code on my website

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" 
method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="YOUR_PRODUCT_NAME" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
<input type="number" name="amount" value="5" placeholder="5" min="5"/>
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
</form>
```

Since this code is easily visible on the source code of my web page

1) Anyone can see my email

2) Anyone can change the code to start paying say EUR 0.01. Since I will be charged for each transaction 1.9% + EUR 0.35, someone can easily piss me off!

Please let me know is it safe!

Note :

1)I have no issue regarding payment with a changed price since I will first see the transaction and then deliver the product.

2)I don't want a hosted button because I need variable pricing and don't want to use donate button (as it is not for personal blog fundraising, I guess).

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone could see your email address even easier after clicking on the button. It's on the top of the page where you can enter the amount you want to pay

Comment: You also won't get charged fees bigger than the amount you would receive. If someone wants to pay you 0,01€, you need to pay 0,01€ fees.

Comment: _"I have no issue regarding payment with a changed price"_ . Based on this comment, you are _contradicting_ yourself about "security" so what you have is "enough" (for you). Safe? **Absolutely not**,  but that seems _what you want or are "ok" with_.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do it with the standard buttons. A user could easily tamper the payment between your site and PayPal. The only way to do it would be with the encrypted website payments.

Read more here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0P017Q

You must be comfortable programming in scripts like PHP and ASP to use Encrypted Website Payments.

This will make your payment buttons tamper proof.